# Handling missing values in lag column of dataframe

Tags: dataframe, date, julia, lag

I need to find difference between sucessive datetimes ... and split the file when I find a time difference of more than 5 minutes. When I subtract periods I get answers in milliseconds and there is also a missing value in the lagged column. If I skip the missing value, then I can't update the dataframe. Not sure how to proceed.

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
using ShiftedArrays: lag 
using Dates
df = CSV.read(IOBuffer("""
date
2024-01-25 19:15
2024-01-25 19:20
2024-01-25 19:25
2024-01-25 21:20
2024-01-25 21:25
"""),DataFrame; dateformat=DateFormat("yy-mm-dd H:M"))
condf=transform(df,[:date,:date] => ((x,y)->Dates.CompoundPeriod.(skipmissing(x-lag(y,1)))) =>:ldate)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what you want to do with the rows with `missing` value.

If you want to get rid of them then use the `dropmissing` function before your operation.

If you want to keep it it depends on what do you assume that the `missing` actually held. The easiest is to probably use `Impute.locf` or `Imputel.nocb` function from Impute.jl to fill `missing` with the value that will give you the desired split.

If what I write is not clear then please comment (best would be if you would show the input and desired output - including `missing` values in the example).

Some additional cases to consider:

- what would you want if the data started/ended with `missing` values?
- what would you want if there were several consecutive `missing` values?
- is it guaranteed that the data frame is sorted by timestamp column?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could use Impute to get rid of any missing values in the dataframe, but that wouldn't solve my immediate problem ... which is that  x-lag(x) introduces a missing value at the start and removing it causes a failure because the column is no longer the right size for the dataframe.

Comment: I really need to insert a ::CompoundPeriod value into the vector returned by the skipmissing() function. I've tried various syntaxes for this and failed.

Comment: NB. Error message when running the code above is ...ERROR: ArgumentError: New columns must have the same length as old columns

Comment: As I have commented above - I am not fully clear what output you expect. Can you please provide an example input and expected output?

Comment: I have n lines with a time stamp. They fall into m clumps with 5 minutes between pairs of lines. So I will split the n lines into m files and each file will have a sequence of timestamps with exactly 5 minutes between times.
I can solve this problem in R with a few lines of code,  but I'm trying to learn julia and keep running into "little" problems. Like the missing value when I build the lag column which stops me adding it to the dataframe. 

td=transform(dfunique,[:date,:date] => ((x,y)->Dates.CompoundPeriod.(x-lag(y,1))) =>:ldate)

Comment: td=transform(dfunique,[:date,:date] => ((x,y)->Dates.CompoundPeriod.(x-lag(y,1))) =>:ldate)

or if I skip the missing value, the column is too short and I can't add it to the dataframe.

td=transform(dfunique,[:date,:date] => ((x,y)->Dates.CompoundPeriod.(skipmissing(x-lag(y,1)))) =>:ldate)

Comment: P.S. Thanks for your attention. I've been reading your J&DA book; it's terrific.

Comment: Eventually found a clumsy way of getting the column I need to break up the dataframe by chunk of lines ... assuming dfunique is the dataframe ... 

gaps(x) = pushfirst!(Dates.CompoundPeriod.(skipmissing(x-lag(x,1))),Dates.CompoundPeriod(Millisecond(300000)))
dfunique.ldate=gaps(dfunique[:,:date])